# Compare values of 2 ranges; generates error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understand why this generates error 13...Type MisMatch

```
Dim workingWs, stageWs as Worksheet
Dim dataWsLastRow, dataRngLastRow as Integer

If workingWs.Range("A1:A" & depthRngLastRow).Value2 = stageWs.Range("A1:A" & dataWsLastRow).Value2 Then
        targetWs.Range("E8").Value2 = stageWs.Range("I1:I" & dataWsLastRow)
        targetWs.Range("E9").Value2 = stageWs.Range("J1:J" & dataWsLastRow)
 End If
```

The If Then statement is throwing an error 13.
Thanks!

More context:
workingWs col a has 14 unique depth values:
say 5000, 50000, etc. each depth value has a different number of values in col i and col j. I'm comparing col a to col a in workingWs and stageWs and need to return col i and col j....for each instance of the unique depths, in specific areas of the target worksheet. Hope this helps clarify the problem.

Comment: You can't compare a single value to an array. Nor can you store the value of a multi-cell range in a single-cell.

Comment: Nor can you check directly for equality between two arrays.

Comment: Each unique value in workingWs col A has a different number of values in stageWs...how may I capture this dynamic range. Also, how do I modify line 1?

Comment: It might make sense to explain in broad terms what you're trying to do.

Comment: You will need to loop one of the ranges and test if it is found in the other, I would suggest Application.Match() to test and return the row in which the match is found.  Then after testing that the match returned a number you can use that to return the correct value.  But really I looks like you are trying to mimic VLOOKUP.

Comment: The `IF` line wouldn't compile `"A1:A" & depthRngLastRow"` - you need remove the last `"`.  `workingWs` is an empty variant variable.   `depthRngLastRow` is equal to 0 if you haven't got `Option Explict`.... none of your variables contain a value. Please have a read of [mcve] - I'm getting syntax error, not type mismatch.

Comment: the last " was a a typo. after depthRngLastRow. I'll remove it now from the post